# Does a PR remain after its associated branch is deleted?

Tags: github, pull-request

If I delete a private github branch, does an associated pull request remain?

Comment: What happens when you test it?

Answer (score 0):

In a word - no. Deleting a branch will automatically close any outstanding pull request issued from it.

Restoring the branch won't automatically restore the pull request, but will allow you to manually do so.